# Calculate rolling distinct count in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following data:

```
     date_  user_id
2021-10-05      123
2021-10-05      234
2021-10-05      345
2021-10-06      123
2021-10-06      234
2021-10-06      111
2021-10-07      123
2021-10-07      234
2021-10-07      111
2021-10-07      122
```

which is produced by this piece of code:

```
select 
  date('2021-10-05') as date_, '123' as user_id
  union all select date('2021-10-05'), '234'
  union all select date('2021-10-05'), '345'
  union all select date('2021-10-06'), '123'
  union all select date('2021-10-06'), '234'
  union all select date('2021-10-06'), '111'
  union all select date('2021-10-07'), '123'
  union all select date('2021-10-07'), '234'
  union all select date('2021-10-07'), '111'
  union all select date('2021-10-07'), '122'
```

What I want to do is to calculate the rolling count distinct of the `user_id` field for the previous rows of **each date**. The result should be this:

```
     date_       rolling_count_distinct
2021-10-05                            3
2021-10-06                            4
2021-10-07                            5
```

It's like running the following piece of code, but for all dates in the `where` clause (`'2021-10-05'`, `'2021-10-06'`, `'2021-10-07'`):

```
with table_1 as (
   select 
      date('2021-10-05') as date_, '123' as user_id
      union all select date('2021-10-05'), '234'
      union all select date('2021-10-05'), '345'
      union all select date('2021-10-06'), '123'
      union all select date('2021-10-06'), '234'
      union all select date('2021-10-06'), '111'
      union all select date('2021-10-07'), '123'
      union all select date('2021-10-07'), '234'
      union all select date('2021-10-07'), '111'
      union all select date('2021-10-07'), '122'
   )

select
  count(distinct user_id) as rolling_count_distinct
from table_1
where date_ <= '2021-10-05'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select date_, (
  select hll_count.merge(users)
  from t.users
) as distinct_users_count
from (
  select date_, array_agg(hll_count.init(user_id)) over(order by date_) users 
  from your_table
  group by date_
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the only way to work with `distinct` in window functions is to make them arrays. One problem with this solution is how big `arrays` table can in real life data problems.

```
with table_1 as (
   select 
      date('2021-10-05') as date_, '123' as user_id
      union all select date('2021-10-05'), '234'
      union all select date('2021-10-05'), '345'
      union all select date('2021-10-06'), '123'
      union all select date('2021-10-06'), '234'
      union all select date('2021-10-06'), '111'
      union all select date('2021-10-07'), '123'
      union all select date('2021-10-07'), '234'
      union all select date('2021-10-07'), '111'
      union all select date('2021-10-07'), '122'
   ),
arrays as (
select
  date_ ,array_agg(user_id) over (order by date_) as rollin_users
from table_1
)

select distinct date_, (select count(distinct users) from unnest(rollin_users) AS users) 
from arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
with agg_data as (
select t1.date_,
  array_agg(distinct t2.user_id) agg_user
from sample_data t1
left join sample_data t2
 on t1.date_ >= t2.date_
group by date_
)

select date_,
  array_length(agg_user)
from agg_data t1
```

With your sample data it produces the following:

[image]

This approach allows you to simplify the process of generating the running aggregate by distincting the values that go into an array then counting the length of the array.